# Why are the values not written to sheets before another function is called using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

The function below gets the rows of data from a web app based form, finds the row in the spreadsheet based on 2 criteria and sets the values to the destination in that sheet.
Even if the data coming in is intended to a row only, the function takes about 15 seconds to finish and that is because another function is called after the `forEach()` and `setValue()` part of the process.
Shouldn't the values be written to the spreadsheet and not necessarily wait for the called function to finish, since that function does something independent?

```
function formToSheets(rows) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(10000);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 10 seconds.');
  }
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const atSht = ss.getSheetByName('Approval Tracker');
  const atValuesRng = atSht.getDataRange();
  const atValues = atValuesRng.getValues();

  rows.forEach(function (item) {
    for (let a = atValues.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
      if (item[0] == atValues[a][9] && item[1] == atValues[a][11]) {
        let row = a + 1;
        atSht.getRange(row, 3).setValue(item[6]);
        atSht.getRange(row, 8).setValue(item[7]);
      }
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const clientId = rows[0][0];
  //Updates the Client's Project Workbook
  updateClientFile(clientId, rows);
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

This is the 2nd function:

```
var clientSeoProjectWbId = [];
function updateClientFile(clientId, rows) {
  searchaFolder_(DriveApp.getFolderById('ID'), clientId);

  let data = rows.map(e => [e[6], e[3], e[2], e[4] != '' ? e[4].split('"')[1] : '', e[5]]);
  const clientFileId = clientSeoProjectWbId[0];
  if (clientFileId == undefined) {
    const recipients = "email";
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,
      'Subject',
      'msg body');
    return;
  }
  const clientSeoProjectWb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(clientFileId);
  const atSht = clientSeoProjectWb.getSheetByName('Approval Tracker');
  atSht.getRange(atSht.getLastRow() + 1, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}



//Searches for the client's workbook within all folders and subfolders in the parent folder whose ID is passed as a param
function searchaFolder_(_aFolder, clientId) {
  var clientIdSearchTerm = "title contains '" + clientId + "'";
  var clientFiles = _aFolder.searchFiles(clientIdSearchTerm);
  while (clientFiles.hasNext()) {
    var aFile = clientFiles.next();
    if (aFile.getName().indexOf('Workbook') > -1) {
      clientSeoProjectWbId.push(aFile.getId());
      if (aFile.getId() != '') break;
    }
  }
  //Iterates through the subfolders
  var someFolders = _aFolder.getFolders();
  while (someFolders.hasNext()) {
    var newFolder = someFolders.next();
    //launch function again with new folder
    searchaFolder_(newFolder, clientId);
  }
}
```

I've tried running it without calling the second function and it takes 03 seconds, which is acceptable.

Appreciate your thoughts/direction(s)!

Comment: Try using SpreadsheetApp.flush() when you want to be sure that the spreasheet has been updated.

Comment: Tried it, @Cooper! Didn't change the timing. Thanks anyway

Comment: Where exactly did you implement SpreadsheetApp.flush()?

Comment: Hi, @ziganotschka! I did put it outside/after the ```rows.forEach()...``` piece, after the "loop" where values are set.

Comment: You can try to flush after each `atSht.getRange(row, 8).setValue(item[7]);` iteration. Also, for debugging purposes, you can log the current timestamp both within each loop, after `forEach()` and at the start of your second function. E.g. `console.log('a: ' + a + ", timestamp: " + new Date())`.

Comment: Thank you, @ziganotschka! I'll try that. I'm sure the second function takes long to execute, since it iterates through indefinite folders and its subfolders, but I was wondering why the first function awaits for it before it sets the values where needed. Thank you!